# Recent crackdown on 430 EUR personal limit for goods into the EU

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, shipping

I am moving from the UK to the Netherlands and was planning on taking my most valuable personal goods with me rather than trust them to the shipping company. The shipping company inform me that in the last few weeks the customs people have been strictly applying the 430EUR limit on bringing good across the border. Has anyone encountered this issue - how would you even be able to bring your laptop with you?

Comment: If you are a Dutch resident, you're not *supposed* to bring a laptop with you from abroad, that's what the €430 is about. Bringing back a laptop you bought in the EU and you took with you on a trip is a different thing. And moving to the Netherlands is yet another situation. In that case, there is [procedure to bring valuable goods](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/international_migration_and_removal_goods/from_a_non_eu_country/) but there is some paperwork involved.

Comment: I find it a bit odd that your shipping company tells you about restrictions on items that are "not shipped". How would they know? Can it be that they want to scare you into using their services? Even if you ship them you would probably not have to pay any duty if you declare them as zero value which is reasonable with depreciated items. Of course, you can insure them in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out to be a non-event. Customs guy swabbed the car steering wheel (drugs? explosives?), then looked in the car, chock full of stuff, and asked who it belonged to. I said me. He then asked if I had anything to declare. I said a bottle of scotch and two bottles of port. He said that's fine, enjoy your drinks. Off I went.